# Quarkus with Swagger UI apply global authorization

Tags: authentication, swagger, swagger-ui, endpoint, quarkus

I have configured OpenAPI using `@OpenAPIDefinition` annotation to show the authorize (button) on the Swagger UI, but currently it has no functinality, when I try to authenticate it does nothing (no request is performed).

What I want to achieve is authenticate via the authorize button on the Swagger UI; then extract the token and pass it as a Authorization header on all endpoints.

How to configure and utilize the authorize functionality and then make it available globaly for all endpoints?

My application is secured using the HTTP with Bearer method.

Current config of the Swagger UI authentication

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(
    info = @Info(
            title = "My API",
            version = "1.0.0"
    ),
    components = @Components(
            securitySchemes = {
                    @SecurityScheme(
                            securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth",
                            type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
                            scheme = "bearer",
                            bearerFormat = "JWT"
                    ),
                    @SecurityScheme(
                            securitySchemeName = "basic",
                            type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
                            scheme = "basic"
                    )
            }
    ),
    security = {
            @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"),
            @SecurityRequirement(name = "basic")
    }
)
public class CustomApi extends Application { }
```

Comment: What happens if you only keep the `basic` security scheme ?

Comment: Bearer authorization requires you to have the token already.

Comment: @Haroon yeah that was only what I was lacking. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

You need to also add the token url into the definition, so Swagger-UI knows how to retrieve the token and authenticate. I have a sample working here: https://github.com/radcortez/microprofile-samples/blob/042e4d349a09a8505b25b880dd4f3e0095b55369/services/book-api/src/main/java/com/microprofile/samples/services/book/BookApplication.java#L40-L55.

Please, let me know if that works for you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Roberto, but apparently my issue was with the Bearer auth. I resolved this issue by performing a login request first and then applying the token on the authorize section manually. Not sure if there's a way to automate this process...